# Use of same Named Trackers across 2 doomains

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, cross-domain, tracker

Implementing google analytics cross-domain tracking between a site and its shopping cart on another domain. On the WordPress site, have kept the original profile id to maintain continuity in reporting for the sole domain:

**WordPress site**

```
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['o._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-4']);
  _gaq.push(['o._trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['xd._setAccount', 'UA-yyyyyyy-1']);
  // other cross-domain parameters are set here... 
  _gaq.push(['xd._trackPageview']);
```

On the shopping cart site, do I need to use the same named tracker to keep the cookies straight? I.e., do I need on the second site to have

**shopping cart domain**

```
_gaq.push(['xd._setAccount', 'UA-yyyyyyy-1']);
_gaq.push(['xd._trackPageview']);
```

Or could it remain the default:

```
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-yyyyyyy-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

What is the effect in each case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to, but if you do it will work either way.

Comment: Hey Eduardo - we seem to keep meeting on Google Analytics question...thanks. 

It will work, but do the same cookies get found? I'd like to understand in more details how cookies work in relation to trackers and Google's docs are not very detailed... If you are trying to track attribution across domains (eg, the email campaigns a visitor originally came from, etc.) does the tracker need to find the same cookie store?

Comment: In this case you specified it will use the exact same cookie for both trackers. There are some ways you can specify trackers to use different cookie sets but it's very easy to break stuff if you do it and don;t understand what's happening. The cookies get set at whatever domain you set at _setDomainName and at the path you set at _setCookiePath. So if you want to have 2 sets of cookies you need to store them in separated paths or domains.

Comment: But you gave me a good idea for a blog post. To try to explain exactly how trackers get mapped into cookies for Google Analytics.

Comment: Anyway, the tracker name plays no role at all on the cookie level. It's just a label for when you have multiple trackers on the same page. It's not related to the cookie set they're acting on. And if they have the esact same settings of _setDomainName and _SetCookiePath they will allways act on the same cookie set.

Comment: Ah, that is really helpful Eduardo - and I want to read your blog post. I though there was a relation between named tracker and cookie store. You are saying there is only a relation between cookie path or setDomainName and cookie store. This is really useful information and I hope you will write about it...

Comment: Could you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134151/jquery-indexof-error-for-xdomain-js-cross-domain-link-script