# jQuery indexOf error for xdomain.js cross-domain link script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, cross-domain

I'm using a script to detect cross-domain links for google analytics cross-domain tracking. The original script (xdomain.js) was provided by the great folks at Luna Metrics.  Here is the script with my modifications, hat-tip to educardocereto here on StackOverflow for the suggested changes to enable setAllowAnchor in the GATC (I've commented line 40 where the console error first points to):

```
var jQueryXD = jQuery.noConflict();
/* I added var because page loads 2 versions 
    of jquery - not the source of the problem.*/

function listenToClicks()
{
    var domains=["domain1.com", "domain2.com"];
    var fileTypes=[".pdf"];

    jQueryXD('a').each(function(index) {
        var link = jQueryXD(this);
        var href = link.attr('href');

        jQueryXD.each(fileTypes, function(i) {
            if(jQueryXD(link).attr('href').indexOf(this)!=-1){ //this is line 40
                valid = false;
                jQueryXD(link).bind('click', function(c) {
                    c.preventDefault();
                    _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent('Download', 'Click - ' +      jQueryXD(link).attr('href'));
                    setTimeout('document.location = "' + jQueryXD(link).attr('href') + '"', 100);
                });
            }
        });

        var valid = false;
        jQueryXD.each(domains, function(j) {
            try
            {
                if((jQueryXD(link).attr('href').indexOf(this)!=-1)&&(window.location.href.indexOf(this)==-1)){  
                    valid = true;

                    if (valid)
                    {
                        jQueryXD(link).bind('click', function(l) {
                            if(typeof(_gat)=="object"){
                                l.preventDefault();
                                if (jQueryXD(link).attr('target') != "_blank")
                                {                               // _gaq.push(['_link',jQueryXD(link).attr('href')]);
                                    _gaq.push(['_link',jQueryXD(link).attr('href'), true]); // mod
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var tracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
                                    //var fullUrl = tracker._getLinkerUrl(jQueryXD(link).attr('href'));
                                    var fullUrl = tracker._getLinkerUrl(jQueryXD(link).attr('href'), true); //mod
                                    window.open(fullUrl);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
            catch(e)
            {
                //Bad A tag
            }           
        });

        var rootDomain = document.domain.split(".")[document.domain.split(".").length - 2] + "." + document.domain.split(".")[document.domain.split(".").length - 1];

        if ( (href.match(/^http/)) && (href.indexOf(rootDomain) == -1) && !valid) {
            jQueryXD(link).bind('click', function(d) {
                    d.preventDefault();
                    _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent('Outbound Link', href);
                    setTimeout('document.location = "' + href + '"', 100);
                });            
        }
    });

}

jQueryXD(document).ready(function() {
    listenToClicks();
});
```

The output from the Chrome javascript console:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: 
Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined        xdomain-nfi-nfs-anchormod-noconflict.js:40
    jQueryXD.each.valid                          xdomain-nfi-nfs-anchormod-noconflict.js:40
    jQuery.extend.each                           jquery-1.2.6.min.js:21
    (anonymous function)                         xdomain-nfi-nfs-anchormod-noconflict.js:39
    jQuery.extend.each                           jquery-1.2.6.min.js:21
    jQuery.fn.jQuery.each                        jquery-1.2.6.min.js:12
    listenToClicks                               xdomain-nfi-nfs-anchormod-noconflict.js:35
    (anonymous function)                         xdomain-nfi-nfs-anchormod-noconflict.js:100
    jQuery.fn.extend.ready                       jquery-1.2.6.min.js:27
    jQuery.extend.ready.jQuery.readyList         jquery-1.2.6.min.js:27
    jQuery.extend.each                           jquery-1.2.6.min.js:21
    jQuery.extend.ready                          jquery-1.2.6.min.js:27
```

So, atleast it seems to be not mixing up the two jquery instances. I've also tried it with jquery 1.7.1. I'm using 1.2.6 because the script seems to have been moste tested on that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you cache both the jQuerified element and the href attr.

```
var link = jQueryXD(this);
var href = link.attr('href');
```

Than why do you later do this:

```
jQueryXD(link).attr('href').indexOf(this)
```

You could either call `link.attr('href').indexOf(this)` since `link` is already a jQuery object or you could use directly the href you cached and do this `href.indexOf(this)`.

Still I think the error you see happens when a link doesn't have an href attribute. So you better check if the href is not undefined before continuing your logic.

I tested it on both jQuery 1.2.6 and 1.7. It seems to be working fine.

Here's the finished script.

```
var jQueryXD = jQuery.noConflict();
/* I added var because page loads 2 versions 
    of jquery - not the source of the problem.*/

function listenToClicks() {
    var domains = ["domain1.com", "domain2.com"];
    var fileTypes = [".pdf"];

    jQueryXD('a').each(function(index) {
        var link = jQueryXD(this);
        var href = link.attr('href');
        if(!href){
            // This element doesnt have a href
            return true;
        }

        var valid = false;
        jQueryXD.each(fileTypes, function(i) {
            if (href.indexOf(this) != -1) { //this is line 40
                valid = false;
                link.bind('click', function(c) {
                    c.preventDefault();
                    _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent('Download', 'Click - ' + link.attr('href'));
                    setTimeout('document.location = "' + href + '"', 100);
                });
            }
        });

        jQueryXD.each(domains, function(j) {
            try {
                if ((href.indexOf(this) != -1) && (window.location.href.indexOf(this) == -1)) {
                    valid = true;

                    if (valid) {
                        link.bind('click', function(l) {
                            if (typeof(_gat) == "object") {
                                l.preventDefault();
                                if (link.attr('target') != "_blank") { // _gaq.push(['_link',jQueryXD(link).attr('href')]);
                                    _gaq.push(['_link', href, true]); // mod
                                }
                                else {
                                    var tracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
                                    //var fullUrl = tracker._getLinkerUrl(href);
                                    var fullUrl = tracker._getLinkerUrl(href, true); //mod
                                    window.open(fullUrl);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (e) {
                //Bad A tag
            }
        });

        var rootDomain = document.domain.split(".")[document.domain.split(".").length - 2] + "." + document.domain.split(".")[document.domain.split(".").length - 1];

        if ((href.match(/^http/)) && (href.indexOf(rootDomain) == -1) && !valid) {
            jQueryXD(link).bind('click', function(d) {
                d.preventDefault();
                _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent('Outbound Link', href);
                setTimeout('document.location = "' + href + '"', 100);
            });
        }
    });

}

jQueryXD(document).ready(function() {
    listenToClicks();
});
```

But you might be reinventing the wheel here. There are some better scripts out there to achieve the same thing. I think you might be interested in looking into [GAS](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas). It's a wrapper around ga.js that extends and add a bunch of stuff including crossDomain and downloadTracking.

Spoiler: I'm the main developer of [GAS](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas).

https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas

Comment: I just downloaded GAS; wow -- looks like this is what I will now be using... there was a recent [LinkedIn post](http://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&srchtype=discussedNews&gid=66386&item=91547917&type=member&trk=eml-anet_dig-b_pd-ttl-cn&ut=0GksdAi443QR41) in the Advanced Web Metrics group re scroll tracking (which I see GAS is also doing) that Brian Clifton joined in on.

Comment: Is there anything in GAS to be aware of in terms of setAllowAnchor to switch to the '#' delimiter?

Comment: GAS is very smart in terms of _setAllowHash. If you use ['_setAllowHash', true], than all xdomain links will be tagged respecting that. Please let me know if you find any problem with it. This is a project from my company, so we take bugs very seriously and tend to fix them fairly quick

Comment: Hi Eduardo - you mean I think setAllowAnchor not setAllowHash (deprecated)?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mean _setAllowAnchor. You're right _SetAllowHash is deprecated and is not used in GAS